# How can i include partial view conditionally according to the passing array from controller or not

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have a master view page where included multiple partial views passing array from controller.
 i want to create a new page extends master.

But don't need all partial of master page into my new one.

So i want to include partial views into master according to passing array from my controller.

means *** if i pass arrary from controller then partial view will be included else not.***

Offcouse foreach will be enable if the partial views getting array from the controller.

[image]

***it can be done using if condition but i want to solve this using 
includeIf() directive according to laravel documentation.***

please suggest how can i achieve this.

Comment: Don't post your code as an image... Code is text, copy and paste it into the question please.

Comment: ok thanks. i will from next

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like so:

```
@if(!empty($galleryImages))
   @include('includes.home.photo-gallery', ...);
@endif
```

Comment: it's ok but how can i get using this.  @includeIf('view.name', ['some' => 'data']); ?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:

```
@if(!empty($photo_galaries))

    @include('includes.home.photo-gallery', [
        'photo_galaries' => $photo_galaries,
    ]);

@endif
```

Change the code from line 65 on file `news-template.blade.php` for this.

Hope it helps.